# nginx: [warn] protocol options redefined

Tags: nginx

I'm updated nginx to 1.23.4, and `nginx -t` start showing warnings:

```
nginx: [warn] protocol options redefined for 0.0.0.0:443 in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/beta:5
nginx: [warn] protocol options redefined for [::]:443 in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:28
nginx: [warn] protocol options redefined for [::]:443 in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/grafana:5
```

These lines are

```
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
# sometimes:
#    listen 443 ssl;
#    listen [::]:443;
# I'm now know - some inconsistency, fixed
```

But after tweaking and adding `http2` there were more warnings.

Answer (score 5):

It turned out that I didn't correct the configuration enough. Corrections must be made on all servers configurations.

To find all the wrong occurrences, you can help yourself:

```bash
grep -R /etc/nginx/ -e 443 |grep -v ssl
grep -R /etc/nginx/ -e 443 |grep -v http2
```

Important: **All servers listening on the same port should have identical configuration.**

eg.:

```
listen 443 ssl http2;

#bad:  ssl without http2
listen 443 ssl; 

#ok:   identical protocols as in previous (first) server
listen 443 ssl http2;
```

More details are in commit: https://github.com/nginx/nginx/commit/dad65f3e449f215469943628f2b1f12a118fcf7e

Comment: which corrections did you apply?

Comment: Some servers I had defined as `443 ssl` others `443 ssl http2`. After fix all are `443 ssl http2`

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the message shows each time that the nginx configuration processor encounters a listen directive for a given ip address & port combination that is different to the previous one it saw.

So if you have two consecutive `server` blocks that have the same listen directive then you will NOT get a warning for the second one. If the `server` block that follows that has a different listen directive (e.g. the same as the first one) then that will trigger another warning.

Ultimately, the solution is to make sure they are all the same, but I hope this extra detail helps somebody somewhere narrow down which of their configuration files they should change.

Comment: More details in nginx commit: https://github.com/nginx/nginx/commit/dad65f3e449f215469943628f2b1f12a118fcf7e

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue because the default_server block did not include the `ssl` directive.

So it should have been:

```
server {
  listen 443 default_server ssl;
  listen [::]:443 default_server ssl;

  ...
}
```

instead of

```
server {
  listen 443 default_server;
  listen [::]:443 default_server;

  ...
}
```

Note that in other server blocks which also listen on 443, I had included the `http2 on;` directive, but this was **not necessary** to include in the `default_server` to make the warning go away.